# Can Kinect 360 do hand gesture recognition?

Tags: windows, kinect, tracking

Now I know the officially supported model for kinect sdk is the kinect windows, but the price difference between kinect 360 and kinect windows is almsot 3 times. I could buy kinect 360 for 100 bucks while I can't find any one selling kinect windows below 250.

not to mention that kinect 360 is widely sold in every major store while only 1 vendor is selling kinect windows in my region. the limited supply means the price won't change because there's no competition.

anyway, I just want to know whether kinect 360 can do what I need for my project. I am trying to do hand gesture and motion recognition using kinect, basically using it to do desktop operations like click, drag, and drop, and I need to do it for both hands. from what I know
- only kinect windows can do close mode.

does kinect 360 have enough resolution to recognize hand motions?

Answer (score 0):

The only main difference between the Kinect for Windows and the Kinect for Xbox 360 is the range. Kinect for Windows has [Near Mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kinectforwindows/archive/2012/01/20/near-mode-what-it-is-and-isn-t.aspx). There is no difference in processing, or internal hardware except for Near Mode. See [this question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/654/what-is-the-difference-between-kinect-for-windows-and-kinect-for-xbox) for some more exact details, but for what you are trying to achieve the Kinect for Xbox 360 will work fine.